# Transparent div "above" map blocking dragging

Tags: leaflet

I have a full screen map with a sibling div that appears "above" the map. The div is a full width 3 column flex, the left and right columns contain information panels (green in the diagram), the centre one is empty (pink in the diagram):

[image]

As far as the user is concerned, the pink column doesn't exist.

The problem I'm facing is that the center column is blocking drag events on the map, moving the mouse over it changes the pointer from a drag handle to a pointer.

It seems the standard solution for this is to add

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to the blocking div. I've tried this and it seems to make no difference, so I'm wondering if there's some Leaflet specific knowledge I'm lacking in regard to this.

Anyone got any ideas? Any suggestions welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can giving the center column a class. 
for example:

class "center-column"
and put some css rule, like this:

```
.center-column {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that, I set the z-index below the map and tried setting the position too (I'd be interested to know what you're thinking was behind the positioning, I'm not sure what the intention was). Anyway, it didn't work sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to a mistake I made. Since my map was full screen, I've given it's container the following styles:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
z-index: -5000;
```

It looks like reducing the z-index of the map to be underneath the panels was the wrong way to do it. Removing the z-index: -5000, and increasing the z-index of the panels resulted in the same display, but without the problem!